# Как работать с github composer

Tags: github

Такой вопрос как работать с github composer хочу [скачать этот класс целиком](https://github.com/php-curl-class/php-curl-class) беда в том что не знаю как, объясните на понятном языке.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

На самом деле, вам незачем работать с GitHub напрямую. В экосистеме Composer'а существует [хранилище пакетов](https://packagist.org). Более того, библиотека [php-curl-class](https://packagist.org/packages/php-curl-class/php-curl-class) есть в хранилище пакетов.

Итак, все, что вам нужно сделать, это установить Composer (см. [официальную документацию](https://getcomposer.org/download/)) и поставить необходимый вам пакет. Вот так:

```
$ composer require "php-curl-class/php-curl-class"
```